# PHP 7.4 iiS No input file specified for only one site among other site

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, iis, windows-server

Hi There,
Recently I have migrated 5 Websites from one windows server to another with higher capacity. After the migration, I configured all 5 sites in the same manner. But among 5 sites only one site is showing "No input file specified". I have referred to the previous solutions and all the solutions are to modify the root PHP.ini Even though I modified it by commenting and uncomment ";doc_root =", giving inetpub value to the same, and modifying handlers..etc but no luck. Below is the PHP config

[image: PHP MANAGER]

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured Request Restrictions in IIS for the *.php handler?

Open the IIS manager, find *.php in the Handler Mappings module under the server node, double-click to open its properties, and configure it as follows:

[image: image1]

Then click "Request Restrictions", select in the Mapping tab: "Invoke handler only if  request is mapped to", and check the "File".

[image: image2]